# How to get only the clicked element in JQuery

Tags: jquery

How to get only the clicked element in JQuery

Suppose the following

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div>
      <h1>headding</h1>
    </div>
    <a>link</a>
  </body>
</html>

$("*").click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   alert($(this)[0].tagName);
});
```

I need when click on `h1` the alert show `h1`
and when click on `a` the alert show `a` etc.

The problem is when i click on any element the code make loop to show name of all parents element of the clicked element. but i need only the first clicked element. any help

Comment: use  e.stopPropagation();

Comment: You shouldn't ever bind events to `*`.

Answer (score 13):

use [stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) so the event doesn't bubble up

```
$("*").click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   e.stopPropagation();
   alert($(this)[0].tagName);
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wirey00/JGvW2/)

Answer (score 4):

You need a `return false` at the end to prevent the bubbling up.

```
$("*").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert($(this)[0].tagName);
    return false;
});
```

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BVQGe/)

Comment: Need is a very strong word and so rarely correct. The `stopPropagation` function would achieve the same thing, so you most certainly don't *need* `return false`.

Comment: And `stopPropagation` is probably better because it actually reflects the wanted behavior.

Comment: Returning false may have been appropriate in certain situations... but in this one, stopPropagation() is the more needed one!

Comment: `return false` will call `e.stopPropagation` in addition to `e.preventDefault`, which may not be intentional.

Answer (score 4):

You're running into event propagation. The event originates from the element that you clicked on, but is then propagated up the DOM tree to the root (the document). You can use the [`stopPropagation`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) method to prevent this, or `return false` from the event handler function (to both prevent the default behaviour **and** stop propagation):

```
 $("*").click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   e.stopPropagation();
   alert(this.tagName);
});
```

Or

```
$("*").click(function(e){
   alert(this.tagName);
   return false; //both prevents default and stops propagation
});
```

As an aside, `$(this)[0]` is nonsense. You're creating an array-like object containing `this`, then getting the first element (`this`) back out, so it's unnecessary function calls and array access to obtain something you already have a direct reference to. Pure overhead for zero gain, just use `this` directly.

Answer (score 1):

Just change your jQuery selector to only add a click event to `h1` and `a`:

```
$("h1,a").click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   alert($(this)[0].tagName);
});
```